# Android unit testing for flow with emitAll

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a function that return flow by emitAll

```
 fun handle(actions: MoviesActions): Flow<MoviesStates> = flow {
    when (actions) {
        is MoviesActions.LoadMovies -> {
            emit(MoviesStates.Loading)
            emitAll(moviesUseCase.execute())
        }
    }
}
```

And this the use case function

```
suspend fun execute(): Flow<MoviesStates> = flow {
    combine(f1, f2) { state1: MoviesStates, state2: MoviesStates ->
     
          // some code
        
    }.collect {
        emit(it)
    }
}
```

No problem in testing the first emission `MoviesStates.Loading`, the problem is when I try to test the flow which return from usecase by emitAll `emitAll(moviesUseCase.execute())`, the test fails and I got this result

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: Expected at least one element

this is my unit test

```
@Test
fun testLoadMovies() = runBlocking {
    whenever(useCase.execute()).thenReturn(flow {
        MoviesStates.EmptyList
    })

    val actual = viewModel.handle(MoviesActions.LoadMovies).drop(1).first()
    val expected = MoviesStates.EmptyList

    assertEquals(actual, expected)
}
```

**So How can I test it correctly?**

Comment: You should collect the emissions in the test and then assert on what you collected. If you don't want to do it manually, I suggest you try [turbine](https://github.com/cashapp/turbine/). Also, a small note: in `execute` you don't need to create a new flow through `flow {`. You can just return `combine(f1, f2) {`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [gpunto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292745/gpunto) , this is the solution he suggested

```
@Test
fun testLoadMovies() = runTest {
    whenever(useCase.execute()).thenReturn(flow {
         MoviesStates.EmptyList
    })

    useCase.execute().collectLatest { states ->
        val actual = viewModel.handle(MoviesActions.LoadMovies).drop(1).first()
        val expected = states 
        assertEquals(expected, actual)
    }
}
```